# What would the climate of a Pangaea-Ultima-inspired world be like?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, earth-like, climate

In a sci-fi scenario, human explorers have discovered a binary of G0 stars, each one 105% as wide, 110% as massive and 126% as bright as our sun.  Orbiting this binary within its habitable zone is an Earthlike planet with a landmass arranged exactly like our prediction of the future supercontinent "Pangaea Ultima".

[image]

There are several crucial differences between this world and ours:

1. A day lasts 26 hours, not 24.
2. Because of its orbit around binary stars larger and brighter than our sun, it rotates 872 times to make up one revolution.
3. Carbon dioxide makes up 4500 parts per million in the atmosphere, whereas oxygen makes up one-third of the atmosphere.
4. Its axial tilt ranges from 19.7 to 26.9 degrees.

Even the oceans differ from our own.

- Shallow seas= 53%
- Deep seas (1-4km)= 32%
- Abyssal plains (5-6km)= 3%
- Trenches and deeps (deeper than six kilometers)= 12%

The mountains similar to those presented in the image vary in height from Andean to Himalayan.

With all the information provided above, what would the climate map of this Pangaea-Ultima-inspired alien world look like?

Comment: I was thinking about the greenhouse effect 10x CO2 would produce,  But then realized that temperatures could not be estimated without an estimate of solar energy coming down on the planet.   It could be a snowball world.  It could be uninhabitably hot except for the poles.  Or somewhere in between.

Comment: What is the size of the planet? The albedo(Albedo is a measure of how reflective a planet is, on a scale of 0 to 1.)? I have to agree with Willk as well. The carbon dioxide is at a deadly level.

Comment: I recently read somewhere that they predict temperatures to be very high temperatures in such a future continent. I think as much as 50 to 60 degrees Celsius inland. Which would be way to hot for most mammals. There also very somewhat cooler areas i think in the northern hemisphere.